# dplyr-summarise, keep the original group name

Tags: r, dplyr

```
iris %>% mutate(subgroup=rep(c('A','B'),75)) %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(SLmin=min(Sepal.Length))



  Species    SLmin
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 setosa       4.3
2 versicolor   4.9
3 virginica    4.9
```

I want to keep the original subgroup name.
but

```
iris %>% mutate(subgroup=rep(c('A','B'),75)) %>% group_by(Species,subgroup) %>% summarise(SLmin=min(Sepal.Length))

  Species    subgroup SLmin
  <fct>      <chr>    <dbl>
1 setosa     A          4.4
2 setosa     B          4.3
3 versicolor A          5  
4 versicolor B          4.9
5 virginica  A          4.9
6 virginica  B          5.6
```

this code cannot get minimum at each species.

do you know any idea?

PS:

It was hard to explain, so I'll fix it.

I need subgroups.
After summarizing the results.

```
setosa     B          4.3  
versicolor B          4.9
virginica  A          4.9
```

Comment: Every `Species` have multiple `subgroup`s which is the original subgroup?

Comment: Which version of dplyr are you using? For example, in dplyr 1.0.2, in `summarise()` function you should use the argument `.groups`. However to keep the variable `subgroup` as grouping variable you can reorganize your grouping level as `group_by(subgroup, Species) %>% summarise(..., .groups = "drop_last")`.

Comment: dplyr is ‘1.0.2’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `which.min` to get index of minimum value of `Sepal.Length`, this index can be used to subset corresponding `subgroup` value.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(subgroup=rep(c('A','B'),75)) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(SLmin=min(Sepal.Length), 
            subgroup = subgroup[which.min(Sepal.Length)])

#  Species    SLmin subgroup
#  <fct>      <dbl> <chr>   
#1 setosa       4.3 B       
#2 versicolor   4.9 B       
#3 virginica    4.9 A
```

---

Also an alternative is to select the minimum row for each `Species` and then select only those columns that we need in the final output.

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(subgroup=rep(c('A','B'),75)) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(which.min(Sepal.Length))
```